# Could not find server 'server name' in sys.servers. SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I recently upgraded our SQL Server from 2005 to 2014 (linked server) and I am noticing that one of the stored procedures which calls the exec command to execute a stored procedure on the upgraded linked server is failing with the error

> Could not find server 'server name' in sys.servers.Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

The issue is that the linked server exists and I have done tests to ensure I can query the tables from the linked server. Here are the checks I did to see if the linked server is configured correctly.

```
 - select name from sys.servers -- > Lists the linked server 
 - select top 10 * from linkedserver.database.dbo.table -->  Gets top 10 records 
 - exec linkedserver.database.dbo.storedproc --> Executes the stored procedure (I created a test stored procedure on the linked server and I can execute it)
```

However the one that is failing with the error is below

```
exec linkedserver.database.dbo.failing_storedprocedure  @id,'load ','v2',@file_name, @list_id = @listid output;
```

I've recreated the linked server and RPC is enabled.I've granted execute permission on the stored procedure. I can select records and execute other stored procedures on the linked server but the above exec is failing(it worked before the upgrade).Is there a syntax difference between SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2014 that is causing this to fail?

Comment: I had the same message but my cause was a dot in the database-name see [this answer from db-name not in sys-servers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23110264/819887)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The linked server was created correctly. However, after the server was upgraded and switched the server name in `sys.servers` still had the old server name.

I had to drop the old server name and add the new server name to `sys.servers` on the new server

```
sp_dropserver 'Server_A'
GO
sp_addserver  'Server',local
GO
```

Comment: Note, this no longer works in sql server 2014 - it results in the message: "Feature "sp_addserver" is no longer supported. Replace remote servers by using linked servers."

Comment: we need to use 'sp_addlinkedserver' going forward to add server

Answer (score 50):

At first check out that your linked server is in the list by this query

```
select name from sys.servers
```

If it not exists then try to add to the linked server

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'SERVER_NAME' --or may be server ip address
```

After that login to that linked server by

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'SERVER_NAME'
                         ,'false'
                         ,NULL
                         ,'USER_NAME'
                         ,'PASSWORD'
```

Then you can do whatever you want ,treat it like your local server

```
exec [SERVER_NAME].[DATABASE_NAME].dbo.SP_NAME @sample_parameter
```

Finally you can drop that server from linked server list by

```
sp_dropserver 'SERVER_NAME', 'droplogins'
```

If it will help you then please upvote.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem due to an extra space in the name of the linked server.
"SERVER1, 1234"
instead of
"SERVER1,1234"